# Parent's padding influences vertical relative padding of child in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm using the established method for keeping an element's ratio by setting a relative `padding-bottom`.

The relative vertical margins and paddings are relative to the width of the containing block, as is width itself.

The width in this case is apparently the one of the *padding-edge*, so including the padding. A 100% absolute child will cover the parent's padding.

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  
  background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

The code should render the `.inner` at 60 x 60 px², right?

There shouldn't be a difference in assigning `height: 100%` or `padding-bottom: 100%` to the child, right?

This is the case in Firefox, but not in Chrome. What's going on?

Apparently Chrome (and Safari) is taking the containing box's padding into account, which it shouldn't.

Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 and Opera also render the right size

Comment: It looks like Firefox is counting parent padding when calculating child padding and Chrome does not count parent padding (that is why 10px gap is shown in Chrome). When using width or height these two browsers counting parent padding (as specified here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property ). I did not found if browsers should take parent padding into account when counting child paddings so I think that it is different implementation by browsers. So I would use width and height as it works identical in these browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Height is not a solution for the problem though since you cannot keep a ratio independent of the  parent's height. The only workaround is to use 2 elements to get rid of the padding.

Comment: From the section above on your link: "2. Otherwise, the containing block is formed by the padding edge of the ancestor. "

Comment: Opera shows the (presumably) correct behaviour only with the Presto engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug in Webkit and Blink – or it's just not specified, as Sergiy pointed out.

I consider it a bug since `width: 100%` is taking paddings into account, and any other % units should behave the same.

I filed a [bugreport](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=589824#c4) which got accepted, it's fixed in v52 of Chrome.

Safari 10.1 still has the issue.